# Examples of abstract objects (like sheaf cohomology) with computational perspectives (Čech cohomology)

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, soft-question, homological-algebra

The derived functor perspective on sheaf cohomology is useful for developing theory, but when we calculate it, we use Čech cohomology.
Likewise, we can see group cohomology as a right-derived functor, but for calculations, we use more concrete objects coming from projective modules.
Both of these examples come from the fact that we can calculate derived functors using acyclic objects.

What are some other examples of this principle? I'd be interested either in different derived functors or something completely different.

Comment: I think a great majority, or maybe even almost all, examples of such things are things that are defined by some universal property and where one has a theorem that some particular construction has that universal property. Do you consider things like cartesian products to be examples?

Comment: Sure, but I guess I am hoping for examples where the 'computational perspective' isn't immediately obvious - maybe it elicits a sense of surprised gratitude for the student who's just read the abstract definition. But maybe this is silly, since historically mathematicians usually come up with the computational perspective first. (Thanks for articulating the general principle though, might help me think of examples myself)

Answer (score 4):

One nice example of this, which is also sheaf theory, but of a different flavour, is cohomology in the algebraic topology sense. One often learns the definition and proves the abstract properties via singular cohomology, completely un-computable (besides formal stuff). Then one learns of the many fantastic tangible alternate methods of computing it, with a triangulation, with a CW decomposition, with differential forms, with a Morse function, with a Cech cover, and so on.